# How to disable Symbol.hasInstance for inheritors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I created a proxy class `B` that redirects instantiation checks to the class `A` via `Symbol.hasInstance`. So, if I run the `instanceof` check against the `B` class, any inheritor of the `A` class will pass.

However, I want to inherit the `B` class, and I don't want the inheritors to follow the `B` class logic. I would like them to have their original identity and run the default `instanceof` logic for them. In the code below it is a `C` class.

However, by default, the `Symbol.hasInstance` property is inherited. How can I disable it for children classes?

```js
class A {}

class B {
  static [Symbol.hasInstance](instance) {
    return instance instanceof A;
  }
}

class C extends B {}

class D extends A {}

const d = new D();

console.log(d instanceof B); // should be true
console.log(d instanceof C); // should be false
```

I already tried the following code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(C, Symbol.hasInstance, {value: null});
```

It works for Chrome and Firefox but does not work for Edge throwing the following error:

```
The value of the property 'Symbol[Symbol.hasInstance]' is not a Function object
```

Is there any other way to remove/disable the `Symbol.hasInstance` that works in Edge as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a method, and you can check which class it was called on using the `this` context. So fall back to the default implementation for everything that is not `B`, and therefore likely was a subclass of it that inherited the method:

```
class B {
  static [Symbol.hasInstance](instance) {
    if (this === B)
      return A.prototype.isPrototypeOf(instance);
    else
      return this.prototype.isPrototypeOf(instance);
  }
}
```

(Notice you cannot use `instanceof this` here, as that would lead to infinite recursion)